# How to modify android Source code and use that into Android device?

Tags: android, linux, shell

First my task is: to permanently remove the Bottom menu from Tables Android 4.0.4, which includes back , home and menu keys. I don't want that, as per my requirement.

I have gone through number of blogs and posts available on internet about "How to modify Android Source code". But none of them is clear about exactly changing the Source code and then use that in device.

I mean i downloaded Android source code using [Hiding and Showing System Bar(Status Bar + Navigation Bar) in Android Tablets using Android Source Code](http://pradeep-ki-duniya.blogspot.in/2013/03/hiding-and-showing-system-barstatus-bar.html)

[1](http://pradeep-ki-duniya.blogspot.in/2013/03/hiding-and-showing-system-barstatus-bar.html): http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html and got some idea about changing source from [here](http://pradeep-ki-duniya.blogspot.in/2013/03/hiding-and-showing-system-barstatus-bar.html)

but nothing clear to me. 
Can anyone point me to the clear blog or video which can help me because its a week of googling and still unable to get it done.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is so generic. So I just suppose that you have already got to know how to build and flash your customized firmware. And here is the answer for your original requirement:

To disable the navigation buttons, you should modify the file **YOURANDORIDROOT/framework/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml**
and change the value

`<bool name="config_showNavigationBar">true</bool>`

to

`<bool name="config_showNavigationBar">false</bool>`

And some more information for your reference, you can go to framework/base/package/systemui directory and there you can find the source code of the status bar.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i would do that and let you know if it works. It will work on Android 4.0.4?

Comment: I know how to build but can you please point me to right direction that how to flash your custom firmware?

Comment: I have checked that file and in Android 4.0.4 its already FALSE. What you would suggest now?

Comment: Please follow the official guide, use fastboot to flash the images. Check the section of "Flash a Device" on this page http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html

Comment: Please go to check the source code of the statusbar. check the frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/NavigationBarView.java and other related files.